# Hosting drupal on s3 with s3fs

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal-7, s3fs

Can we mount S3 on file system and move drupal docroot to s3? Will this setup work? Has anyone tried this?

Mount s3 on /var/www/drupal7
copy drupal files to /var/www/drupal7 folder and point apache docroot to that folder.
I appreciate it, if someone can comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you are doing the filesystem stuff on os level, drupal should not complain about that. you could use the sites/*/files directory only for S3, too. There are modules for that.